# Numerical solution to PDE (using finite difference) is oscilating heavily at boundary, is this possible?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, finite-differences

I am solving a PDE using finite difference which is of the following form:

$F(x,y) =a_{1} F(x+\Delta x,y)+a_{2} F(x-\Delta x,y)+a_{3}F(x,y+\Delta y)+a_{4}F(x,y-\Delta y)$

Where $a_{i}$ are known constants. Furthermore the values of F at the boundaries are known. When I solve this using matlab the solution at one of the boundaries is heavily oscilating. [Link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhulR.jpg). This is the most extreme one, depending on the parameters, the intensity of oscilation varies.

I think this should not be the case but after checking my code multiple times I did not find an error. Has anyone had experience with oscilating solutions at the boundary? Is this something that can happen or can I assume there is an error in the code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be useful to post your code and the explicit example you are using.

Comment: Also, why don't you state the whole problem? Different PDEs with different boundary conditions behave differently.

Comment: That's a little weird, because the only PDE it could come from would be $f=(a_1-a_2)f_x + (a_3-a_4)f_y$, so the $a_i$ are slightly arbitrary.

Comment: The PDE I try to solve is the following: $\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{1}^2F_{xx}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{2}^2F_{yy}+\mu_{1}F{x}+\mu_{2}F_{y}=rF$ where all coefficients are known. This comes from real option theory, where F describes the value of having the option to invest, given some state (x,y). F is defined in the $x,y \geq 0$ quadrant and the boundary is a square. Now the boundary conditions: For (x,y) where x=0 we have F(x,y)=-E (E is known) and for (x,y) where y=0 we also have F(x,y)=-E. The value on the other two boundaries is a linear and an log function, which are too long to state here